# Oct2Py on Windows 10 hanging

Tags: python, windows, octave, oct2py

I previously had Oct2Py version 3.4.0 working with Octave 4.0.0 on windows 7, but now I am trying to get Oct2Py on Windows 10. The install worked just fine and I can import Oct2Py, but when I try to run

```
    oct2py.addpath("some\path")
```

My python console stops responding.

I saw on this thread: 
https://github.com/blink1073/oct2py/issues/63
that there are issues with windows and Oct2Py but I tried going back to an older version of Oct2PY and that still didn't work. Does anyone know if there is a way to get Oct2Py to run in my setup??

Comment: Seems like a question best answered by the developer.

Comment: Just a guess; does the path that you tried accidentally contain any [escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals)?

Comment: No, I was thinking it could be a problem with the path but I've tried using both "/" and "\" and also tried copying the path from the file properties and pasting it directly so I don't think the path is the issue